# AWS .NET Core 2.0 - DoesS3BucketExistAsync fails

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc

March 2018: I am coding up AWS Lambda functions using .NET Core 2.0 on VS2017. This is the latest version of the AWS .NET SDK that uses async methods.

I need to check that an S3 bucket exists - which it does. I've created an S3 Client which I know is working because I can "do stuff" to the bucket, put an object etc.

My checking method is coded as follows:

```
    public async Task VerifyStorageBucketExistsAsync(string myS3BucketName)
    {

     bool bolDoesBucketExist = await s3Client.DoesS3BucketExistAsync(myS3BucketName);
     if (!bolDoesBucketExist)
         throw new Exception(String.Format("myS3BucketNamebucket {0} does not exist", myS3BucketName));

    }
```

Called with:

```
await myS3Manager.VerifyStorageBucketExistsAsync();
```

which is in an async task.

My checking method works just fine on my home development machine - not behind a firewall etc.

The checking method throws the "bucket not found" exception when run from my work development machine - which is behind a corporate firewall. But note, that the other bucket operations do succeed. The S3 Client is good and I can put/get objects. It is only the DoesS3BucketExistAsyn() method that fails.

Finally, the checking method runs just fine when published to AWS Lambda itself. It's only when run from the work dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

From 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3UtilDoesS3BucketExistAsyncIS3String.html

`Determines whether an S3 bucket exists or not...... Making a HEAD request to the Url`

'HEAD request' need access to the IAM Action "s3:ListBucket", if you don't have the action, you will get a Fordibben error, this can be tested with the CLI.

If the bucket exists and you have access to it, no output is returned. Otherwise, an error message will be shown. For example:

```
aws s3api head-bucket --bucket my-bucket-demo
An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadBucket operation: Forbidden
```

Comment: Thanks. The IAM account does have the ListBucket permission. That doco is also old - most of the AWS .NET SDK doco need a major update. It really doesn't explain why it works on a dev machine (home, not behind firewall etc) and in AWS Lambda, but not on my work machine (behind firewall). The firewall might be a red herring...

Comment: Are you using the same policy for the dev and work? have you checked with cli commands? I guess, its a credential mismatch.

Comment: Thanks again. And yes, credential are the same. Everything is the same in that regard. I'm thinking now that our firewall / proxy is getting in the way somehow... its not a show stopper but these things bug me.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, its does make actual HTTP Head request. Here is the doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html